# Usage of "it" in English Grammar

Tags: grammar, pronouns

Is using "**it**" with common names grammatically correct?

For example:

> Who drink this Tea?. **It's** John.

Comment: That's correct, but not idiomatic. *John does* is the most common answer form.

Comment: To be precise the question is more likely to be `Who's tea is this?` with a response of `It's John's.`

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with the commenter who said "John does" is more idiomatic. If anything, that's a more "proper" response, but definitely not idiomatic and definitely not the way most English speakers (at least in the US) would respond.

If someone said, "Who's drinking this tea?", I would simply say "John." "It's John" also sounds fine, though. Or even "John is."

If someone said, "Who's tea is this?", I might say "John's" or "It's John's."

But, to answer your question, in general, you can use "it's" with names. The first example of this that I thought of is when you answer a phone: "Hello? Who's this?" "Hi, it's John."